# Load balancer in EC2 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am working on AWS. I have a doubt regarding how many applications a load balancer can support.

Like if I have an application whose traffic is routed and managed by one load balancer, then can I use that LB for another application also???

Also if I can use that ELB for another applications also than how ELB will get to know that which traffic should be routed to Application A server and which to Application B server??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding the role of the load balancer. The whole point of a load balancer is that *any* of the servers behind it can provide *any* of the services. By setting it up this way you ensure that the failure of any one server will not affect availability of the service.

You can load balance any TCP service such as HTTP just by adding it as a "listener" for the ELB. The ELB can therefore support as many applications as you want to forward to the servers behind it.

If you set up an image of a server that provides all the services you need, you can even have the ELB auto scale the number of servers up and down by launching or terminating instances from that image as the load varies.

Comment: how will the ELB knows how to redirect the request to application A server or B server ???

Comment: Since both servers provide the service it doesn't matter which one. The ELB will choose one that is free according to an algorithm that will distribute the load evenly between all the servers so that no server gets overloaded.